# multiple sun function in a query in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have 3 tables on mySQL database. **product, stock_in, stock_out**. I want to sum total **stock in** and **stock out** of each product by **product_id**.
I use this query below. But it gives me some false answers.

```
SELECT product.Product_Name, SUM(stock_in.StockInQuantity) as stockin, S
        SUM(stock_out.Quantity) as stockout 
FROM product, stock_in, stock_out 
WHERE stock_in.Product_ID=product.Product_ID 
and stock_out.Product_ID=product.Product_ID 
GROUP BY product.Product_ID**
```

But if I use separate queries for `stockin` and `stockout`, results are correct.

```
SELECT Product_Name, SUM(StockInQuantity) as stockin 
FROM product, stock_in 
WHERE stock_in.Product_ID=product.Product_ID 
GROUP BY product.Product_ID


SELECT Product_Name, SUM(Quantity) as stockout 
FROM product, stock_out 
WHERE stock_out.Product_ID=product.Product_ID 
GROUP BY product.Product_ID**
```

So please give me a solution to find the result in one query or to echo results of two query results in one table..

Comment: Due to Joins, you are getting rows duplicated. Here is a possible approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52474658/2469308

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select Sum from two joined tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474336/select-sum-from-two-joined-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query:

```
SELECT p.product_name AS Product_Name,
   COALESCE(SUM(si.stockin), 0) AS total_stockin,
   COALESCE(SUM(so.stockout), 0) AS total_stockout,
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Product_ID, SUM(StockInQuantity) AS stockin
       FROM stock_in 
       GROUP BY Product_ID) si ON si.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Product_ID, SUM(Quantity) AS stockout
       FROM stock_out 
       GROUP BY Product_ID) so ON so.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
GROUP BY Product_Name
```