# Mysql Distinct Sum Aggregation On Join Operation

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a query like below:

```
Select t1.field1
     , sum(t2.field2)
     , sum(t3.field3) 
  from table1 t1
  left 
  join table2 t2 
    on t1.field1 = t2.field1
  left 
  join table3 t3  
    on t2.field1 = t3.field1 
   and t2.date = t3.date
group by t1.field1;
```

Assume table contents looks like below:

```
table1:
-field1-
  test
  test1
  test2     

table2:
-field1- -field2- -date-
  test      5       0
  test      4       1
  test      3       2
  test1     3       2

table3:
-field1- -field3- -date-
  test      1       0
  test      2       1
  test      3       2
  test      3       3
  test      3       4
  test      3       5
```

When I run query, query gives to me as result:

```
-field1-   -sum(field2)-  -sum(field3)-
  test          24              15
  test1         3              null
  test2        null            null
```

**The problem in here;** sum(field2) contains repeated values that come from left join operation. I want to show sum(field2) according to sum of distinct table2 field2 values.
So I want to get result as:

```
-field1-   -sum(field2)-  -sum(field3)-
  test          12              15
  test1         3              null
  test2        null            null
```

Note: Please don't suggest to me derived table option because I know this can be solved with derived table (left join (Select ... from table3 ... group by field1, field2)).

Comment: Check this answer for a hacky (but efficient approach): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52474658/2469308

Comment: How test `SUM(field3)` give 15? I get 12 with duplicates and 6 without duplicates

Comment: Another approach is to use [Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52474822/2469308

Comment: And what is the problem with derivative tables?

Comment: @Sha . . . Your desired results don't seem to be taking `date` into account.  The sum should be 6 or 9, depending on whether you want to count the duplicates from the `join`.

Comment: Your sum result seams to be multiplied by the join(s) one-to-many or many-to-many relation joins can do that -> So `Select t1.field1
     , sum(distinct t2.field2)
     , sum(distinct t3.field3)` `Select t1.field1
     , sum(t2.field2) / count(t2.field2)
     , sum(t3.field3) / count(t3.field3) ` would fix that.. Note this will most likely not scale well on large results as the aggregation is done twice in the rather case where the distinct would process a large set.. As you commented somewhere you didn't want to use the derived table solution

Comment: Raymond and Madhur, When I implement your solution, I get "Error 1111: Invalid use of group function"

Comment: @Sha what is the query that you are trying to run. Please ensure that you have to specify all the non-aggregated column in the select list in the group by clause as well

Comment: Provide a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ example with the query your are trying  as your current ascii data example can't be used in tools to reproduce your question or problem..

Answer (score 1):

Try this below option-

```
SELECT A.field1,B.field2,C.field3 
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT field1,SUM(field2) field2 
    FROM Table2 GROUP BY field1
)B ON A.field1 = B.field1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT field1,SUM(field3) field3 
    FROM Table3 GROUP BY field1
)C ON A.field1 = C.field1
```

Comment: I know the derived table solution but this is not better way for performance so I didn't use derived table solution.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-aggregate the results:

```
select t1.field1, t2.sum2, t3.sum3
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.field1, sum(t2.field2) as sum2
      from table2 t2 
      group by t2.field1
     ) t2
     on t1.field1 = t2.field1 left join
     (select t3.field1, sum(t3.field3) as sum3
      from table3 t3 join
           table2 t2
           on t2.field1 = t3.field1 and t2.date = t3.date
      group by t3.field1
     ) t3
     on t3.field1 = t1.field1;
```

This is tricky, because you have condition on `date` between `table2` and `table3`.

Your specified desired results don't seem to be taking `date` into account, which simplifies the logic somewhat:

```
select t1.field1, t2.sum2, t3.sum3
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.field1, sum(t2.field2) as sum2
      from table2 t2 
      group by t2.field1
     ) t2
     on t1.field1 = t2.field1 left join
     (select t3.field1, sum(t3.field3) as sum3
      from table3 t3
      group by t3.field1
     ) t3
     on t3.field1 = t1.field1;
```

Comment: You don't need the final `group by t1.field1` in both queries, since `field1` is distinct in all joined tables. It just leads to an `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` error.

Comment: @Sha . . . Getting the logic correct is actually more important than performance.  However, preaggregating the tables should be reasonable from a performance perspective.  Of course, that depends on your table structure, hardware, and database design.